# Help with size of an image for a book

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={11in,8.5in},margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (X) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=10in]{ScreenShot}};%

\begin{scope}[x={(X.south east)},y={(X.north west)}]%
%% This makes all measurements with no units into fractions of the width
%% and height of the graphic contained in the node.
\fill[fill = white,fill opacity=0.6] ($(X.south west) + (0,1in)$) rectangle ($(X.north east) - (0,1in)$);%
\node[text width=10in] (Z) at (0.5,0.5) {%
    \sffamily\centering\Huge Clustering the interstellar medium\\[5pt]
  \normalsize Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy\\[15pt]
  \large Andrea Hidalgo\par%
};
\end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

@Sgmoye showed me this solution for having a transparent text over an image.

My question: how I must change in that code or what I must add to have image the same size as the paper but not in the landscape mode. I've tried some things to work it out, but I didn't succeed. (actually, I add it some height for image, but it looks 'strange'). Any help?

This is how it looks what I want with an observation: image from the half of page must be transparent.

[image]

Comment: You want a background image which covers the whole page some text written on foreground. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, but 'some text' i want to be written on a transparent image.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand `transparent image` in this context. Do you want two images? One for background and another partially covering it?

Comment: yes , like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RGk9B.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution which uses `background` package to include the background image and a `tikzpicture` to define the transparent node for text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{%
contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{frog}}, 
angle=0,
scale=1
}

\begin{document}
\BgThispage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=10cm, outer sep=0pt, fill=green!30, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1, align=center] at (current page.center) {%
    \sffamily\Huge Clustering the interstellar medium\\[5pt]
  \normalsize Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy\\[15pt]
  \large Andrea Hidalgo\par%
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. it's perfect this but.. it set me one picture for all pages and i want it to have only the cover page like that.

Comment: @AndreeaAlistar Sorry for the dealy. It was my mistake, I forgot to load  load package `background` with option `pages=some` (`\usepackage[pages=some]{background}`) which forces to use `\BgThispage` in pages where `backgroundsetup` should appear. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={11in,8.5in},margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[inner sep=0] (X) at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};%

%% This makes all measurements with no units into fractions of the width
%% and height of the graphic contained in the node.
\fill[fill = white,fill opacity=0.4] (current page.south west)  rectangle ($(current page.south east)  + (0,2in)$);%
\fill[fill = white,fill opacity=0.4] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east) + (0,-2in)$);%
\node[text width=10in] (Z) at (current page.center) {%
    \sffamily\centering\Huge Clustering the interstellar medium\\[5pt]
  \normalsize Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy\\[15pt]
  \large Andrea Hidalgo\par%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={11in,8.5in},margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node[inner sep=0,fill = white,fill opacity=0.4] (X) at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};%

\node[inner sep=0] (X) at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.4\paperheight]{example-image-b}};%

%% This makes all measurements with no units into fractions of the width
%% and height of the graphic contained in the node.
%\fill[fill = white,fill opacity=0.4] (current page.south west)  rectangle ($(current page.south east)  + (0,2in)$);%
%\fill[fill = white,fill opacity=0.4] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east) + (0,-2in)$);%
\node[text width=10in] (Z) at (current page.center) {%
    \sffamily\centering\Huge Clustering the interstellar medium\\[5pt]
  \normalsize Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy\\[15pt]
  \large Andrea Hidalgo\par%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

preface #1: I started working on this before the last comments so now I am afraid I misunderstood what you were looking for, however adaptations should be easy.

preface #2: this is 100% not the best solution, but I am trying to learn stuff, so I gave it a shot

Here's what I came up with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{
\noindent\fboxsep=0pt%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{books}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.33\paperheight]{messydesk}};
\node[opacity=0.8,inner sep=0pt]  at (current page.center) {%
    \colorbox{white}{\parbox[c][.33\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{~}}
};
\node[ text width=10in]  at (current page.center) {%
    \sffamily\centering\Huge Clustering the interstellar medium\\[5pt]
  \normalsize Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy\\[15pt]
  \large Andrea Hidalgo\par%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\clearpage
%the actual document
\end{document}
```

the first `node` creates the big image, the second one the smaller one (I now think you might want to get rid of this one), the third one creates an opaque white box simulating "transparency", the last one is the actual text

the result then is something like: (edit: the gray parts is my acroread background, poor snapshot)

[image: cover]

image sources (no infringement intended: www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/what-your-messy-desk-says-about-you-its-a-good-thing-70291/ http://www.alegriphotos.com/Side_of_books-lphoto-93560f5b4dcc9fc387c117d24a686161.html )